# Testing React Hooks side effects that depends on other side effects (or other tests)

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

I have a React Hook that has a simple input and button, and the button is disabled if there is no input, and that same button executes a fetch when it is enabled:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const [ value, setValue ] = useState('')

  function apiRequest() {
    if (!value) {
      return
    }

    axios.get('url')
      .then(console.log)
      .catch(console.log)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} value={value} />
      <button disabled={!value} onClick={apiRequest}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I wrote two tests with [Enzyme](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/). The first one to test if the disabled prop is correct, and the second one to see if it actually fetches.

```js
it('sets the disabled prop appropriately', function() {
    const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />)
    const input = wrapper.find('input')
    const btn = wrapper.find('button')
    expect(btn.prop('disabled')).toBeTruthy()
    input.simulate('change', 'abc123')
    expect(btn.prop('disabled')).toBeFalsy()
})

it('fetches on submit', function () {
    const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />)
    const input = wrapper.find('input')
    const btn = wrapper.find('button')
    input.simulate('change', 'abc123')
    btn.simulate('click')
    expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

But unfortunately for the second test to work, the button needs to be enabled so text has to be inputted first. So in reality, the second test is also unintentionally testing the disabled prop as well because it will fail (the `onClick` will not fire) if the disabled prop isn't set correctly.

I followed React's [recommended approach](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing.html) of

```
test React components without relying on their implementation details
```

which is [react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro)'s core principle, so I'm purely testing side effects. I'm using enzyme instead of that because my team is currently using Enzyme

How would I be able to rewrite my second test so I can *only* test for the fetch? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Or rather, a couple ways to rewrite this to properly test the fetch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is replace the `<div>` with a `<form>` and add the `onSubmit={e => apiRequest(value)}` to it so the button can remain disabled and you can still move forward with your tests without introducing unnecessary external factors.

Also, move your `function apiRequest() {...}` outside of the component.  It can take `value` as an argument instead of relying on the surrounding scope.

```
// You could even export this separately and make a test exclusively for this
// without also having to test the form itself
function apiRequest ( value ) {
    if (!value) {
      return
    }

    axios.get('url')
      .then(console.log)
      .catch(console.log)
}

function MyComponent() {
  const [ value, setValue ] = useState('')

  return (
    <form onSubmit={e => { e.preventDefault(); apiRequest(value); }}>
        <input onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} value={value} />
        <button disabled={!value}>
            Submit
        </button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Comment: Oh very clever with the form! But what if the input and button are not siblings (for example, in a modal - a form in the modal body, and a form in the modal footer - each different containers)? This approach would not be proper, if all I'm doing is wrapping a single button in a form no?

(also the reason I left the function inside is because in my full app, it updates the state as well)

Comment: Oh I'm only addressing the code that's here in the question.  Depending on the situation there could be a ton of different ways to handle this.  It sounds like you're looking for a more conceptual solution than an exact one for this example.  I would suggest checking out [codementor](https://codementor.io) - and I don't even get referral bonus anymore for sharing this :(

Comment: Oh yeah, this was my minimal reproducible example - but it just so happens the solution you provided (totally valid one) made me regret making my example _too_ minimal haha because what I described is actually the situation in my actual code. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

To my believe you definitely are testing behavior, not implementation details.

It would be relying on implementation details if you say were `setState()`(sure it does not work to functional component that's why it's a bad pattern).

Using RTL you still had to change input prior clicking button, no differences here.

The only thing is rather implementation details it's relying on `axios` itself. You may use `nock` to handle any request made with any library. But I'm not sure if that worth it.